# Too large (overaligned?) stack frame with GCC but not with Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, stack, clang, stack-frame

Consider this simple code:

```
class X {
  int i_;
public:
  X();
};

void f() {
  X x;
}
```

The stack frame of `f` is 32-byte long with GCC, which is unnecessarily long. The return address and `x` just need 12 bytes and 16-byte alignment should be required according to the Linux/x86_64 ABI. With Clang, only 16 bytes are allocated. Why GCC requires so much stack space?

GCC assembly:

```
f():
  sub   rsp, 24
  lea   rdi, [rsp+12]
  call  X::X()
  add   rsp, 24
  ret
```

Clang assembly:

```
f():       
  push  rax
  mov   rdi, rsp
  call  X::X()
  pop   rax
  ret
```

Both with `-O2`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bcrWW36on

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating rabbit hole, I've changed my analysis three times already.

It seems that is indeed a missed optimization. While playing around a bit, I found another missed optimization, this time in clang:

If you actually [use the `x` object](https://godbolt.org/z/b5bjov7bW), then Clang uses `rbx` to cache the address of `x` instead of recomputing it, which means it needs to save `rbx` across the function, which extends the used space in the stack frame by 8 (from 12 to 20), bumping the aligned stack frame to 32, same as gcc.

From a debugging perspective, I'd prefer clang to use `sub rsp, 8` instead of `push rax` to allocate the memory for `x`, so the memory isn't marked as initialized in valgrind.

GCC assembly:

```
f():
    sub     rsp, 24
    lea     rdi, [rsp+12]
    call    X::X() [complete object constructor]
    lea     rdi, [rsp+12]
    call    g(X&)
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

Clang assembly:

```
f():
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 16
    lea     rbx, [rsp + 8]
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    X::X() [complete object constructor]
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    g(X&)
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

I've checked whether gcc maybe uses 32 bytes stack alignment by [using a 32 byte vector as a data member](https://godbolt.org/z/5v3xK6j1n), and both gcc and clang generate code to align the stack pointer here, and use the base pointer to implement the variable-length stack frame. I have no idea why Clang allocates 64 bytes for the object here, though.

GCC assembly:

```
f():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -32
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    X::X() [complete object constructor]
    leave
    ret
```

Clang assembly:

```
f():                                  # @f()
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    and     rsp, -32
    sub     rsp, 64
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    X::X() [complete object constructor]
    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Without actually measuring performance, it is hard to tell which is better -- `-O2` will optimize for runtime, not stack frame size, so there could be good reasons for all of these choices.