# Why does unoptimized compiler output sub/add RSP in some functions but not others?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, stack-memory, stack-frame

With reference to the following code:

```c++
#include <cstdint>

void func() {
    return;
}

void funcparent() {
    uint64_t h = 99;
    func();
}

void funcparent2() {
    func();
}

void funcparent3() {
    func();
    int h = 99;
}
```

And assembly, from compiling with no optimization with recent clang for a non-Windows calling convention, [like on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Avoid+func()+%7B%0A++++return%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+funcparent()+%7B%0A++++uint64_t+h+%3D+99%3B%0A++++func()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+funcparent2()+%7B%0A++++func()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+funcparent3()+%7B%0A++++func()%3B%0A++++int+h+%3D+99%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:46.125630444750115,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.87436955524989,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
_Z4funcv:                               # @_Z4funcv
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        pop     rbp
        ret
_Z10funcparentv:                        # @_Z10funcparentv
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], 99
        call    _Z4funcv
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
_Z11funcparent2v:                       # @_Z11funcparent2v
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    _Z4funcv
        pop     rbp
        ret
_Z11funcparent3v:                       # @_Z11funcparent3v
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    _Z4funcv
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 99
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Where is there a `sub rsp, 16` (and subsequent `add`) in `funcparent()` and `funcparent3()`? I thought there is something to do with allocating the stack but `funcparent2()` makes me think otherwise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176276/too-large-overaligned-stack-frame-with-gcc-but-not-with-clang.

It's lowering the stack frame...though I'm not sure why, either, seeing that the stack grows downwards.

Comment: It is reserving space for the local variable `h`.

Comment: @RaymondChen 16 bytes for `h`? and why does it have to incase of the variable being declared before and after the function call?

Comment: @user1280483 yeah I understand it is lowering it, but dont know why...

Comment: It adjusts the stack pointer by 16 so that the stack remains 16-byte aligned.

Comment: This is unoptimized code, so the compiler always allocates stack space for all local variables.

Comment: @prl why for `funcparent3` ? the variable is declared after the function call (I might be missing something very basic)

Comment: @PYA the compiler is allowed to allocate variables anywhere it wants

Comment: @phuclv i don't quite follow. Is there any way to force the compiler to allocate the variable AFTER the function call? in other words, if the compiler allocates the variable after the function call, the `sub` is not needed like in `funcparent2`?

Comment: @PYA why should it allocate after the function call? Typically each stack frame is set up at the beginning only, and both the function and the variable are in the same scope so the variable should be allocated when the stack frame is entered

Comment: @phuclv I see.. but why 16 bytes? if i add another `int` after 'h' it still has a `16` so i am not sure how that relates to allocation

Comment: it's for 16-byte alignment before any function calls as @prl said. Please read the [System V AMD64 calling convention to see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). That allows easier mixing SSE code

Comment: In unoptimized code, the compiler allocates space for all the local variables in the function at the beginning of the function. Is there a way to get it  to do it differently? Yes, enable optimization. Looking at unoptimized compiler output is generally pretty pointless.